# How do I use the @Action Link in MVC C# without the Link Text

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have purchased a Premium Template and have managed to "Crowbar/Shoehorn" the side-Nav, Header & Footer into my _Layout page. However, I do not understand how to apply my @action Link to the Nav-Menu Item. The @action link "Link Text" does not appear to be optional so it conflicts with the Menu item label provided and I am unclear where to apply the @action Link within the HTML provided;

```
<li class="nav-main-item">
  <a class="nav-main-link" href="be_blocks_styles.html">
     <span class="nav-main-link-name">Styles</span>
  </a>
</li>
```

Is there a way to apply this helper without the link text and can you tell me where to apply the "bugger" in order to be able to use the styling provided by the template?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you must use `Html.ActionLink` do it this way

```
@Html.ActionLink("link text", "someaction", "somecontroller", new { id = "53" }, null)
```

So your code becomes

```
<li class="nav-main-item">
    <a class="nav-main-link" @Html.ActionLink("link text", "someaction", "somecontroller", new { id = "53" }, null)>
    <span class="nav-main-link-name">Styles</span>
    </a>
</li>
```

else you can also use `Url.Action`

```
Url.Action("someaction", "somecontroller", new { id = "123" })
```

your code becomes

```
 <li class="nav-main-item">
    <a class="nav-main-link" href=" Url.Action("someaction", "somecontroller", new { id = "123" })">
    <span class="nav-main-link-name">Styles</span>
    </a>
</li>
```

Comment: I used the "Url.Action() and it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

You can use action link and simply apply the bootstrap classes to it.
This will render as an a tag in html. You can then place the span tag inside it